# Bootstrap 4 Nav Bar Collapse not stacking nav items

Tags: html, responsive-design, bootstrap-4, navbar

I have a strange one where my Bootstrap4 Nav Bar collapse is not stacking the nav-items when it expands the menu in narrow mode. I think it has to do with the configuration of the search input in relationship to the nav-items at full width. In order to get the search input to stack left vs the nav-links stacking right I placed them into two separate ul's and applied flex-row with justify-content-between to the parent div. This gave me the full width look I wanted but completely ruined the stacking in the collapsed menu.

Here are images of the collapsed and expanded result in chrome.

[Full width nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yuZ3b.png)

[Expanded collapsed nav](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBL5T.png)

Here is the full code as its just me playing with Bootstrap4

```css
nav{
 -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 -moz-box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 box-shadow: 0px 6px 15px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Smlep5jCw/wG7hdkwQ/Z5nLIefveQRIY9nfy6xoR1uRYBtpZgI6339F5dgvm/e9B" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.1.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-O8whS3fhG2OnA5Kas0Y9l3cfpmYjapjI0E4theH4iuMD+pLhbf6JI0jIMfYcK3yZ" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../C4 Boiler/css/nav.css">
    <title>Boiler Plate</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar sticky-top navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
        <img src="https://picsum.photos/50" width="50" height="50" alt="Test">
      </a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse justify-content-between" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row">
          <form class="form-inline mr-auto">
            <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
            <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">
              <i class="fas fa-search fa-lg"></i>
            </button>
          </form>
        </ul>
        <ul class="navbar-nav flex-row-reverse">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Profile
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
              Info
            </a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
            </div>
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Features</a>
          </li>          
          <li class="nav-item active">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
    </nav>
    <div class="title-box container">
      <div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="project-box container">
    </div>
    <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-o+RDsa0aLu++PJvFqy8fFScvbHFLtbvScb8AjopnFD+iEQ7wo/CG0xlczd+2O/em" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

If anyone has any advice I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks 
Matt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example works fine, almost.

The problem is `.flex-row` and `.flex-row-reverse` class you added on `.navbar-nav`. I see no value added from those 2 classes so I removed them. I reordered your navbar menu items so they go in reversed orders, i.e., from Home, Features, 2 dropdowns.

Also I used `input-group` with addons for your search input because your search button would overflow and went to the next row on small screens. In order to make the search input 100% wide, I used `.w-100` class on it.

**Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/101531/

[image]

[image]

Comment: David thank you so much you are amazing, yes definetly agree the .flex-row and .flex-row-reverse classes were a bit sill. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Just to add that .input-group with .w-100 is pure class!! Top Man.